# Obtaining matrix row as matrix

Tags: r, matrix

What is the shortest way to obtain row from matrix as matrix?

```
> x<-matrix(1:9,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
> x[1,]
[1] 1 2 3
> is.vector(x[1,])
[1] TRUE
```

where I'd like to get

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
```

Comment: Come on Giraphant. Give the check-mark. There really is not any other answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`[` takes a `drop` argument controlling whether the extracted subset will be coerced (if possible) to a lower dimensional object (in this case a plain vector). To ensure that a subset of a matrix will always be a matrix, set it `drop=FALSE`, like this:

```
x[1,,drop=FALSE]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
```

(And for the full set of subsetting rules and arguments, try `help("[")`.)

Comment: That's better, why do I always forget arguments for `[]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This one is better since it will behave same way in two cases. First case is when we have matrix A(3x3) and we want to select more than one row A[1:2,] - result is matrix so no action needed on the other hand A[1,] - is vector so we need convert to matrix (as.matrix) and transpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
t(as.matrix(x[1,]))
```

Should do the trick...